# Convert nested dict containing nested list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a function that extracts certain information from a given website and stores it into a list. The output is a nested dict that looks like this:

```
t = [{'title': ['title1',
   'title2',
   'title3'],
  'link': ['link1',
   'link2',
   'link3'],
  'promo_text': ['text1',
   'text2',
   'text3'],
  'additional_info':['a',
   'b',
   'c']},
 {'title': ['title4',
   'title5',
   'title6'],
  'link': ['link4',
   'link5',
   'link6'],
  'promo_text': ['text4',
   'text5',
   'text6'],
  'additional_info': ['d',
   'e',
   'f']},
 {'title': ['title7',
   'title8',
   'title9'],
  'link': ['link7',
   'link8',
   'link9'],
  'promo_text': ['text7',
   'text8',
   'text9',],
  'additional_info': ['g',
   'h',
   'i']}]
```

I would like to convert this list into a pandas dataframe where the columns are 'title', 'link', 'promo_text' and 'additional_info' so that it looks like this:

|  | title | link | promo_text | additional_info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | title1 | link1 | text1 | a |
| 1 | title2 | link2 | text2 | b |
| 2 | title3 | link3 | text3 | c |
| 3 | title4 | link4 | text4 | d |
| 4 | title5 | link5 | text5 | e |
| 5 | title6 | link6 | text6 | f |
| 6 | title7 | link7 | text7 | g |
| 7 | title8 | link8 | text8 | h |
| 8 | title9 | link9 | text9 | i |

Unfortunately, using the standard pandas command does not seem provide me with the desired output:

```
t_df = pd.DataFrame(t)
t_df
```

|  | title | link | promo_text | additional_info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [title1, title2, title3] | [link1, link2, link3] | [text1, text2, text3] | [a, b, c] |
| 1 | [title4, title5, title6] | [link4, link5, link6] | [text4, text5, text6] | [d, e, f] |
| 2 | [title7, title8, title9] | [link7, link8, link9] | [text7, text8, text9] | [g, h, i] |

Is there a way to convert this adequately using pandas? Any help is much appreciated!

Best,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your list have the same length, you can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(t)
df = df.explode(df.columns.tolist(), ignore_index=True))
```

output:

```
    title   link promo_text additional_info
0  title1  link1      text1               a
1  title2  link2      text2               b
2  title3  link3      text3               c
3  title4  link4      text4               d
4  title5  link5      text5               e
5  title6  link6      text6               f
6  title7  link7      text7               g
7  title8  link8      text8               h
8  title9  link9      text9               i
```